# large memory usage of windows 8 C#/XAML app on one machine but not another machine

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I was working on a windows 8 app in C#/XAML. I was using MVVM pattern, SQLite DB, multiple language support, etc. I did not pay much attention to how much memory the app uses when it runs. It ran reasonably fast. At a certain point I felt that the app rans significantly slower. I was trying to go through the submission process too -- creating the upload packages(for X64, X86, ARM), running the certification test. The app passed the certification test. But I was a little bit concerned about the speed and I was trying to check its memory usage and found that it use several hundred MB memory and at some point the memory can go up to 1GB (based on the number reported in Task Manager). So I tried some debugging and found that before it reaches the second line of the code in App.xaml.cs, it already uses around 150 MB. I tried to load the project into a different machine and ran it there, the memory usage is usually less than 100MB and the speed is what I experienced before it slowed down. So that is normal to me.

So does any of you have some similar experience? Do you have any idea how to make the app work normally on my original machine? My impression is that it has nothing to do what I have in the code. It could be related to some setting I had for the project on my original machine. But I don't know what settings. I tried restart the machine and that did not solve the problem.

After the app became slower, it also crashed more. In the event viewer, I saw the message mentioned the vrfcore.dll. I did some search on that and saw that it is related to application verifier and I did remember trying to run app verifier before. I also tried the debug location in the toolbars too and tried simulating suspension. But the memory is high even when I am not aware of doing those. This problem seemed only affect my app on my machine, but not all the apps.

Comment: Some architectural differences (32 bits vs. 64 bits) can make a difference in size, also debug info adds some overhead, so you may want to compare the performance only of release builds.

Comment: I tried 64 bits on both machines and both release version.

Comment: Are you seeing the high usage on your machine when launched directly and the debugger is not attached?  The jitter knows when the debugger is attached and jits things accordingly, possibly resulting in more memory consumption.

Comment: It did not seem to matter whether I am running debug or just run the app deployed on my machine directly.

Comment: I created a new project from scratch on my machine and added all the files in and build, deploy, add to source control and create the packages. The app behaves normally now. So there is still some mystery regarding to why it behaves slowly in the old project, but at least I got the app work normally on my own machine now.